# Invoking a function multiple times but losing past data

Tags: javascript

Simply working on a homework assignment, at the end, just need to display this method 5 times. Issue is as title states once I invoke the function the next invoke overwrites past invoke.

Heres what I am currently doing.

```
      <p id="table">
      <script type="text/javascript">
            showResults(race[0], name1, party1, votes1);
            showResults(race[1], name2, party2, votes2);
            showResults(race[2], name3, party3, votes3);
            showResults(race[3], name4, party4, votes4);
            showResults(race[4], name5, party5, votes5);
      </script>
      </p>
```

I have used a debugger to try and find a fix, browsed the internet for about an hour now, tried to use a .call but couldn't quite get that working either and I know document.write isn't a viable option because it rewrites everything.

Any help or useful links on the issue would be really appreciated!

Here is the showresults function

```
   function showResults(race, name, party, votes)
   {
        var totalV = totalVotes(votes);
        var result = "";

        result += "<h2>" + race + "</h2>";
        result += "<table cellspacing = '0'>";
        result += "<tr>";
        result += "<th>Candidate</th>"
        result += "<th class='num'>Votes</th>";
        result += "<th class='num'>%</th>";
        result += "</tr>";

        for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) 
        {
            result += "<tr>";
            result += "<td>" + name[i] + '(' + party[i] + ')' + "</td>";
            result += "<td class='num'>" + votes[i] + "</td>";

            var percent = calcPercent(votes[i], totalV)
            result += "<td class='num'>(" + percent + "%)</td>";
            result += createBar(party[i], percent);
            result += "</tr>";
        } 

        result += "</table>";

        document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = result;
   }
```

Comment: We can't really help you without knowing what the `showResults` function does. Could you edit your question to include its source code?

Comment: you've possibly *done something wrong™* in the function named `showResults` - you may also want to show what `race`, `name1`...`name5`, `party1`...`party5` and `votes1`...`votes5` are

Comment: `document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = result;` there you go, each time you call that function you overwrite the content of that element ... simple

Answer (score 0):

The Statement

```
document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = result;
```

Sets the `innerHTML` of your `"table"` element, thus overwriting it each time you set it.

try to

```
append(result);
```

to a existing DOM node so your result gets appended to the document.